Como insretar o anexar archivos en un correo con laravel 10
Buen dia.
quiero isnertar un archivo o anexar un archivo PDF en un correo se ejecuta y todo el unico incoveniente es que el archivo no se ve
esta es mi clase Email.php
public function attachments(): array
{
    $attachments = [];
    foreach ($this->files as $file) {
        // Usar el almacenamiento correcto, si estás usando la carpeta 'public'
        $filePath = storage_path('app/public/' . $file['path']);

        // Verifica que el archivo exista antes de adjuntarlo
        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            $attachments[] = Attachment::fromPath($filePath)
                ->as($file['name'])
                ->withMime($file['mime']);
        } else {
            // Registro de error si el archivo no existe
            Log::error("El archivo no se encontró: " . $filePath);
        }
    }
    return $attachments;
}

aca mi vista de correo .blade donde quiero insertar el correo
  @if (!empty($files))
        <p>Adjunto encontrarás los siguientes archivos:</p>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($files as $file)
                <li>
                    {{ $file['name'] }} ({{ $file['mime'] }})
                    @if ($file['mime'] == 'application/pdf')
                        <embed src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/' . $file['path']) }}" type="application/pdf"
                            width="600" height="400">
                    @endif
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif

NO se ve nada solo el nombre del documento y el tipo de extension
